# Problem accessing audio track from mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, aac, aws-media-convert

For a TV Project we want to transcode the source videofiles to other formats. The Sourcefiles are fragmented mp4 files. Destination format could be mp4 or any other format.
The sourcefile contains multiple audio tracks for different codes (aac, eac3, aac-otherlanguage).

Something with this files is odd. I can play them without problems on quicktime or VLC. Import them into Premiere for example ends up with the video but without sound.

Converting them on AWS MediaConvert results in weird issues as well like (depending on the settings):

- No audio frames decoded on [selector-(Audio Selector 1)-track-1-drc] (selecting aac audiotrack (Track:1))
- Decoder: [Dolby decoder error: failed to configure to stream in first 100 frames] (selecting eac3 audiotrack (Track:2) )

I'm able to convert the files with Handbreak and the result is a MP4 file with one audiotrack which is working everywhere. I'm trying to figure out whats odd with this file to make them working with AWS MediaConvert.

Here is the ffprobe output of one of the files:

```
ffprobe version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfreetype --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '123893.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomiso2iso5dashavc1dby1mp41
  Duration: 00:01:24.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5600 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(deu): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4869 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 1k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(deu): Audio: eac3 (ec-3 / 0x332D6365), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
```

An example file can get downloaded here: https://wilmaa-rnd.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/124041.mp4

Comment: Remux them to a standard MP4 and check.

Comment: This works but i would like to run these files trough AWS MediaConvert...

Comment: So use the remuxed files as AWS input.

Comment: This would be an additional step to develop to process several 100 files every day. I would like to process the files directly in mediaConvert. I'm trying to understand whats odd with these files.